# Hydrostatic force on spillway gate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

I'm designing an spillway gate that, as the water exceeds a specific height, then it opens pure mechanically, it means the hydrostatic force compensates for the weight of the gate. As you can see the gate is hinged in point $A$.[image]

If i try to find out how high water can reach before the gate opens, then i implement two methods:

1) Write the torque equilibrium, clearly this method gives the right answer

2) Use the force balance, when the normal component of hydrostatic force is equal to the weight of the gate, then the gate should move upward and water will flow under it, this method is false, and i spend an awful amount of time to figure it out, but so far i can't find any explanation.

Comment: The normal component of the hydrostatic force is not in the same direction as the weight of the gate and what about the force exerted by the hinge?

Comment: @Farcher Righ, right , i forgot the normal force of the hing, but i don't understand, the hydrostatic force is perpendicular to the side of spillway gate, it means it makes an angle of 30° with the horizontal (ground), so if split it into normal and horizontal components it should have a component in opposite  direction of weight ? where do i make mistake ?

Comment: @chair, this is not a homework, i try to use hydrostatic energy to generate power, it happens to flow water through my property. I'm not going into details anymore.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad I believe that since we're talking about solving equations for a particular system, this qualifies as a homework-_like_ problem. The tag is called homework-_and-exercises_ to cater to problems irrespective of the origins. There are no pending close votes; it looks on-topic to me. But you can feel free to remove the tag if you strongly believe it's inappropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that the water height is at a point where the force at B is exactly zero but the gate has not yet moved upward.

Part of the weight of the gate will now be supported by the hydrostatic force, and part of the weight will be supported by the hinge at point A.

In other words, the hydrostatic force must only lift a portion of the total gate weight.

**Or alternatively**, if your gate CG is far enough left, then the hinge at point A will be pushing the gate down.